# SurfaceView with color transparent

Tags: android, surfaceview

I need to have a background similar to this screenshot, I had a SurfaceView in my Fragment, I this line `android:background="#80FFC107"`, but when I install the app I found only my SurfaceView without color.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, You should use a hex color with Two hexadecimal characters
like : **#66FFC107**

and surfaceview is :

```
 <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/cameraSurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#66FFC107"
            >
```